# jQuery hover issue bug

Tags: jquery, css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9m9k/2/)

To reproduce bug:

1. hover on bbb111 quick few times (quick I mean few times per sec) - best way to do is to move mouse top down (not side/side) I think
2. then hover on bbb111 and on its submenu hover on ccc222.
3. ccc222 has another submenu and it will not show as it should. (main manu will not move down and submenu will not be visable (will
   be under main menu - if you set `overflow:visible` it is visible but
   it is under main menu and main manu still doesnt move down to make
   place for another submenus.

Reproduced on Mozilla, Opera, and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found solution. The problem is that jQuery applies inline style attr to elements and if stop() is fired those styles stays 'as is' in middle of animation, with overflow:hidden stuff etc. Solution is to 'reset' state of menu - add to mouseIn animation callback function `$(this).removeAttr('style');`